# Getting JSON value instead of JSON object in resultset of a GraphQL many-to-one query

Tags: graphql, postgraphile

"employeeByChef" - which is a many-to-one relationship from employee to itself - always returns only one value (scalar) by (relational) definition.

In the JSON response of a GraphQL/Postgraphile query however, a JSON object is being returned (e.g. "employeeByChef": {"name": "Bob"} ... ).

Is there a way in GraphQL/Postgraphile - except writing a view - that the JSON response only returns a JSON value (e.g. "employeeByChef": "Bob")?

```
  query {
    allEmployees() {
      nodes {
        emp_id
        employeeByChef {
          name
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: [computed-columns](https://www.graphile.org/postgraphile/computed-columns/#computed-columns) ?

Comment: Computed columns would be my approach 